# Error to work in reverse VNH2SP30

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, arduino-motor-shield

[image]ım building a rover and ı using Johson 12v Dc motor and VNH2SP30. My code and motor works perfectly but my motor driver works only one way. It cant go to reverse and motor starts buzzing when it tries to go in reverse. Here is the code ım using for testing.

```
#define BRAKE 0
#define CW    1
#define CCW   2
#define CS_THRESHOLD 15   // Definition of safety current (Check: "1.3 Monster Shield Example").

//MOTOR 1
#define MOTOR_A1_PIN 7
#define MOTOR_B1_PIN 8

#define PWM_MOTOR_1 5

#define CURRENT_SEN_1 A2

#define EN_PIN_1 A0

#define MOTOR_1 0

short usSpeed = 150;  //default motor speed
unsigned short usMotor_Status = BRAKE;

void setup()                         
{
  pinMode(MOTOR_A1_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MOTOR_B1_PIN, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(PWM_MOTOR_1, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(CURRENT_SEN_1, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(EN_PIN_1, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);              // Initiates the serial to do the monitoring 
  Serial.println("Begin motor control");
  Serial.println(); //Print function list for user selection
  Serial.println("Enter number for control option:");
  Serial.println("1. STOP");
  Serial.println("2. FORWARD");
  Serial.println("3. REVERSE");
  Serial.println("+. INCREASE SPEED");
  Serial.println("-. DECREASE SPEED");
  Serial.println();

}

void loop() 
{
  char user_input;   



  while(Serial.available())
  {
    user_input = Serial.read(); //Read user input and trigger appropriate function
    digitalWrite(EN_PIN_1, HIGH);


    if (user_input =='1')
    {
       Stop();
    }
    else if(user_input =='2')
    {
      Forward();
    }
    else if(user_input =='3')
    {
      Reverse();
    }
    else if(user_input =='+')
    {
      IncreaseSpeed();
    }
    else if(user_input =='-')
    {
      DecreaseSpeed();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Invalid option entered.");
    }

  }
}

void Stop()
{
  Serial.println("Stop");
  usMotor_Status = BRAKE;
  motorGo(MOTOR_1, usMotor_Status, 0);
}

void Forward()
{
  Serial.println("Forward");
  usMotor_Status = CW;
  motorGo(MOTOR_1, usMotor_Status, usSpeed);
}

void Reverse()
{
  Serial.println("Reverse");
  usMotor_Status = CCW;
  motorGo(MOTOR_1, usMotor_Status, usSpeed);
}

void IncreaseSpeed()
{
  usSpeed = usSpeed + 10;
  if(usSpeed > 255)
  {
    usSpeed = 255;  
  }

  Serial.print("Speed +: ");
  Serial.println(usSpeed);

  motorGo(MOTOR_1, usMotor_Status, usSpeed);
}

void DecreaseSpeed()
{
  usSpeed = usSpeed - 10;
  if(usSpeed < 0)
  {
    usSpeed = 0;  
  }

  Serial.print("Speed -: ");
  Serial.println(usSpeed);

  motorGo(MOTOR_1, usMotor_Status, usSpeed);
}

void motorGo(uint8_t motor, uint8_t direct, uint8_t pwm)         //Function that controls the variables: motor(0 ou 1), direction (cw ou ccw) e pwm (entra 0 e 255);
{
  if(motor == MOTOR_1)
  {
    if(direct == CW)
    {
      digitalWrite(MOTOR_A1_PIN, LOW); 
      digitalWrite(MOTOR_B1_PIN, HIGH);
    }
    else if(direct == CCW)
    {
      digitalWrite(MOTOR_A1_PIN, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(MOTOR_B1_PIN, LOW);      
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(MOTOR_A1_PIN, LOW);
      digitalWrite(MOTOR_B1_PIN, LOW);            
    }

    analogWrite(PWM_MOTOR_1, pwm); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're controlling it right at first glance. Care to share your wiring?

Comment: swap the wires between pin 7 and pin 8

Comment: hi i just added to wires but ıts not perfectly same